# Rails database and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

If I have a form that has a text_field called title and a text_area called text and In my database I generated a model called post with a text:string, text:text how do they relate?

I'm going over the Rails guide and am a little confused on this. Thanks!

Comment: text_field correspond to string and text_area correspond to text

Comment: So if I create a form and I want it to submit data into a column with the name last_name I need to make sure my form has last_name in it? @sp1rs